# YACC&LEX, Getting syntax error at the end of line and can't figure out why

Tags: syntax-error, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm trying to build my compile in lex and yacc for my work
I try for a long time but still get a syntax error in output
this is my yacc

```
%token <ival> DIGIT
%token LOAD
%token ADD
%token MOD
%token SUB
%token MUL
%token INC
%token DEC
%token WS
%token EOL

%%
line :LOAD WS DIGIT EOL{ printf("load_cmd :%d\n",$3);  }
     | ADD EOL{ printf("add!\n");  }
     | MOD EOL{ printf("mod!\n");  }
     | SUB EOL{ printf("sub!\n");  }
     | MUL EOL{ printf("mul!\n");  }
     | INC EOL{ printf("inc!\n");  }
     | DEC EOL{ printf("dec!\n");  }
     ;


%%
```

this is lex:

```
load [l][o][a][d]
add [a][d][d]
sub [s][u][b]
mul [m][u][l]
mod [m][o][d]

inc [i][n][c]
dec [d][e][c]

digit [0-9]+


character [a-zA-Z]




eol [\n\r]

%%

{eol} {return(EOL);}
[\t]+        {return(WS);}
[ ]+        {return(WS);}
{digit}       {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext);return(DIGIT);}
{load}  { return(LOAD); }
{add}  { return(ADD); }
{sub}  { return(SUB); }
{mul}  { return(MUL); }
{mod}  { return(MOD); }
{inc}  { return(INC); }
{dec}  { return(DEC); }


.            {return(yytext[0]);}
%%
```

the input is :

```
load 1
load 2
sub
load 5
mod
```

and the out put is

```
load_cmd :1
syntax error
```

I have already define EOF， but still get a syntax error at end of line, why ?
I cannot figure out why I am getting these results.

there a only one line of output "load_cmd :1", so it may be a EOF problem? or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar describes a single line. So that's what the parser expects.

Parsers built with yacc/bison expect the entire input to match the grammar. So after the parser recognises a `line`, it expects to see the end of the file. When it sees something else, it reports that the input did not match the grammar. In your case, that would happen even if the only thing it sees after the first line is some more whitespace.

A minimal modification to the grammar which allows any number of input lines is:

```
program: %empty
       | program line
       | program EOL
```

The last line allows empty lines in the input.

That needs to go *before* the definition of `line`, since yacc/bison assumes that the *first* non-terminal defined is that root of the grammar. Alternatively, you could put `%start program` into your bison file, to explicitly declare where the grammar starts.

Comment: So how can I correct my code? how can i  give it an EOF?

Comment: this is my first time using yacc, still have a lot to learn....

Comment: @張哲銘: you "give it an EOF" by ending the input after the first line. I don't think that's what you want to do. You want to accept multiple lines, and that means you need to write a grammar which accepts multiple lines.

Comment: @張哲銘: OK, I edited the answer. There's lots more going on in your grammar and scanner which needs attention. I'd start by getting rid of the `WS` token altogether -- whitespace should be ignored, not parsed. Also, I don't know where you got the idea that it's a good idea to add everything twice to flex, once as a macro and the second time as a macro expansion. Macros are just as ugly in Flex as they are in C, and in both cases should be ignored unless strictly necessary. Yours are not at all necessary. Finally, `[l][o][a][d]` is exactly the same pattern as `load`, but it's harder to read.